# What does 到 mean in 哪里可以买到正版的这本书? Does 买到 here serve as a verb-object word?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does 到 mean in this sentence :

哪里可以买到正版的这本书？

Does 买到 here serve as a verb-object word? I doubt it though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「到」(literally *to arrive*) is a verb complement to show whether an action has or can be completed (“arrived at the finished state”).

Since「到」is not actually necessary in this sentence to express the same meaning, it is easier to demonstrate the meaning of「到」with a complementary sentence:

> 那裏**買不到**正版的這本書
>
> The proper version of this book **can’t be bought** there.

X「到」means the action X can be completed, X「不到」means it cannot be completed.

Comment: This is sometimes referred to as a Resultative Verb (结果补语词) where 到 is, as you mentioned, the result.

Comment: Slight inaccuracy at the end: 〔X到〕 means that the result **is** completed (a resultative complement). Conversely, 〔X得到〕 means that the result **can be** (but is not necessarily) completed (a potential complement).

Answer (score 2):

到 is a result complement. 买到 is the shorthand of 买得到.

Sematically, 买到这本书 means you buy and get the book.